# How to use gadget in a ROP attack

Tags: security, x86, 32bit-64bit, buffer-overflow, exploit

Could someone explain what this assembly code does and how could it be used in a ROP attack?
What type of data could go in the registers to successfully perform a ROP attack?
Should it be chained to other gadgets?

```
`xor eax, eax;`
`mov eax, dword ptr [esp];`
`call eax;`
```

For what I know the first instruction performs an exclusive OR (XOR), and sets the register eax to zero. Then the next instruction loads the 32-bit value from the location pointed by esp. Finally, i think the last  instruction calls the function located at the adress stored in the eax.

But i don't know exactly what type of data could go in the registers to successfully perform a ROP attack.

Comment: Those instructions load EAX from the stack and jump to the address, pushing a return address.   So it's kind of like a `ret`, but does `esp-=4` instead of `esp+=4` as well as jumping to an address loaded from stack memory.  The xor-zero of EAX is irrelevant, `mov eax, ...` overwrites the old value.  If the middle instruction was also `or` or `xor`, the first instruction zeroing EAX would matter.  For this gadget to be useful, ESP has to point to somewhere you want to jump.

Comment: That's a very useful gadget. In a ROP chain you control what's in the stack, so you can use that gadget to call into anything you like. If you have ASRL disabled or you already have found an oracle, you can now directly call into `system`.